# sentence capitalizer

Tags: c#, char, sentence

I'm woefully attempting a programming assignment. I'm not looking for a "this is how you do this" but more of a "what am I doing wrong?"

I'm attempting to capitalize the start of each sentence from a string input. So for example the string "Hello. my name is john. i like to ride bikes." I would modify the string and return it with capitals for example: "Hello. My name is john. I like to ride bikes." My logic seems a bit flawed and I'm very lost.

What I have so far below. Basically all I'm doing is testing for a punctuation signifying the end of a sentence. And then trying to replace the character. Also testing if it's the at the end of the string as to not create IndexOutOfRange exceptions. Although, that's all I've been getting :(

```
private string SentenceCapitalizer(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '.' || input[i] == '!' || input[i] == '?')
            {
                if (!(input[i] == input.Length))
                {                       
                    input.Replace(input[i + 2], char.ToUpper(input[i + 2]));  
                }                     
            }
        }

        return input;

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm just learning C# so the most basic of help would be of service. I don't know much :P

Comment: What if you have abbreviation (S.O.L.I.D.) or ellipsis (...) in your text?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if (!(input[i + 2] >= input.Length))
```

It should be

```
if (!(i + 2 >= input.Length))
```

You are comparing indices, not characters

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if your current index is less than or equal to the length of the string and then attempting to alter an index 2 further along

```
    if (!(input[i] == input.Length))
            {                       
                input.Replace(input[i + 2], char.ToUpper(input[i + 2]));  
            }
```

Should be changed to

```
    if (!((i + 2) >= input.Length))
            {                       
                input.Replace(input[i + 2], char.ToUpper(input[i + 2]));  
            }
```

This will check that there is a value 2 places after a punctuation mark. Also make use of >= rather than == since you're jumping 2 you might end up going over the length of the array where == still returns false but there is no index.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. The out of range exception is gone. And it's not working like expected haha, back to the drawing board I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, you can't do:

```
var str = "123";
str.Replace('1', '2');
```

You have to do:

```
var str = "123";
str = str.Replace('1', '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, others have provided you with some pointers to stop the obvious errors,  but I'll try to give you some thoughts on how to best implement this.

It is worth thinking about this as a 3-step process

1. [Tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) the string into sentences
2. Ensure that the first character of each token is uppercase
3. reconstruct the string by joining the tokens back together

(1) I'll leave to your imagination, but the idea is to end up with an array of strings with each element representing a "sentence" according to your requirement

(2) Is pretty much as simple as

```
// Upercase character 0, and join it to everything from character 1 onwards
var fixedToken = token[0].ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
                              + token.Substring(1);
```

(3) Is also simple

```
// reconstruct string by joining all tokens with a space
var reconstructed = String.Join(" ",tokens);
```